# Using Python to tie together a DLA AI

Tags: python, scripting, artificial-intelligence

So, I am completely new to programming. I've been learning basic Python over the last couple weeks. I've always wanted to learn a programming language but right now my primary reason for delving into it is to Create an AI program for my man cave. Here are my Ideas which I am sure have been thought of many times before. They are just my goals:

I would like to take a pre-established open source chat bot and tie it to a Natural Language process to give it the ability to convert my speech to a text command that it can execute and at the same time take its text output and filter it through an audible speech sample (very much like SIRI). This way when I have the function of Natural Language response on, I can have basic conversations with it. I can also turn the conversational aspect off via a voice command so that the only thing it responds to is direct commands (e.g. "Gerard, please open an email, execute. Recipient, logan.wolf.ypher@gmail.com, Subject, Hello World, Body, insert text i speak.)

I would also like to have it recognize that I am there when my phone attempts to connect to the wifi.

I know that this may be a bit complicated for me at the moment but I hear the best way to learn a language is to jump on into a project you enjoy.

Does anyone have any pointers on where to start looking for a base AI or just any tips in general that you wish to give me? I'd appreciate the info very much. Thank you.

-Logan

Comment: Suggest you edit this post and mark as "community wiki", otherwise it will quickly be closed based on being too subjective. Also, maybe consider having it migrated to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `So, I am completely new to programming`, I would recommend you take a smaller part of this project and successfully implement it.  For example, an email account which is checked every 1 minute and you can send textual commands to it.  From there, start upgrading it to use chat, cell phone, speech-to-text, and lastly, AI.  I only say this because I know the diffulculty of starting a too-ambitious project when I am new at an area (electronics, engineering, programming, language, etc...) and fail.  Success, even in small steps, is better!

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I left out the important part that I'm going to try to write this for Linux. I figured it would be easier to find a base open source bot and then share what I've got that way. I appreciate the input. So you are recommending that I start on the peripheral functions before I find an AI/bot to work with?

Comment: What I am saying is to divide the project up into smaller pieces, each of which are **useful** in and of themselves, but when combined together, make a large project.  Then pick your favorite piece and start with it.